# parameters for bitcoin QRCode

Tags: qrcode

im reading up on this page ==> https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0021.mediawiki

I am currently trying to incorporate a message in the qr code but when i proceessed the qrcode it pulled the amount address and amount correctly. but the label didnt seem to appear or the message at all anywhere. i am using blockchain.info and block.io.

I decoded the image and the string is what it should be.

Where is the message stored so customers can view it at a later time?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue resolved. I chose to exclude it as it was no real purpose.